# Order by query post wordpress by select field

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, custom-field-type

I have a select field created with custom field . Field contains a list of numbers from 1 to 10 .

How could do to make the post an ORDER BY query this select?

"orden" is the field select type

Maybe the problem is because the field select is a string?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'directivo',
    'orderby' => 'orden',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'showposts' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'principal_o_suplente',
            'value' => 'principal',
            'compare' => '=='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'empresarios_o_',
            'value' => 'gobiernos',
            'compare' => '=='
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Can you please share your table's structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: _“maybe the problem is because the field select is a string”_ – yes, that’s very likely (although you have so far failed to describe what “the problem” actually _is_.) Try to use `'meta_value_num' ` in that case – https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: thank my friend... it work fine with "meta_value_num"